# JMeter saving sub-millisecond response times to a file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm trying to test an application with a typical resonse times of 0.2-0.4 milliseconds with Apache JMeter. I've found "jp@gc - Response Times Over Time" plugin that is able to *display* such response times as a graph but all available listeners (inluding jp@gc Flexible Data Writer) can save results in a file (for detailed analysis) only at a milliseconds precision. Are there any way in JMeter to save response time at microseconds precision?

Answer (score 0):

There is commented lines in jmeter.properties file:

```
# Whether to use System.nanoTime() - otherwise only use System.currentTimeMillis()
#sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
```

I think if you'll uncomment this option, you'll have higher resolution JMeter results.

Comment: this did not change anything for me in JMeter 3.2